# clean name space and __init__.py

Tags: python, import

I am designing a python package with the following directory structure

```
package\  
    __init__.py  
    subpackage1\  
        __init__.py  
        module1.py  
        module2.py    
    subpackage2\
        __init__.py  
        module3.py
```

I would like users to be able to explore a clean name space that reflects the directory structure using tab completion when importing the package in ipython.

For example, after doing

```
import package as pkg
```

I want tab completion on pkg. to show `pkg.subpackage1 pkg.subpackage2` and tab completion on `pkg.subpackage1`. to show `pkg.subpackage1.module1 pgk.subpackage1.module2`. Some of these modules depend on each other, and include `import statements`.

For example in `module1.py` we have,

```
from ..subpackage2 import module3
```

However, I don't want someone to be able to tab complete the following `pkg.subpackage1.module1.module3` even if they've done `import pkg.subpackage1.module1`.

In addition, when people do `import pkg.subpackage1.module1` I don't want tab completion on `pkg.subpackage1.module1`. to show things like my internal exception classes and the fact that I imported numpy as np in module1.   In other words, I'd like my usage of module3 in module1 to be hidden from the user as well as my usage of numpy as np. Is using things like `import numpy as _np` and `from ..subpackage2 import module3 as _module3` the best way to do this?

Do I have to prepend an underscore to everything I don't want them to see?

To clarify, I can see in the scipy source code that the file scipy.integrate.quadrature has the line `import numpy as np` in it, but when I do `import scipy` in ipython I can tab complete out to scipy.integrate.quadrature and not see np

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quadrature` is a function, not a module.

Comment: yes, but there is a file named quadrature.py in the directory integrate which is in turn in the directory scipy.  doesn't that mean it's a module as well?

Comment: When you import it, you get the function, because in `scipy/integrate/__init__.py`, they have: `from quadrature import *`, which rebinds the name `quadrature` to be the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `package/__init__.py`, include:

```
import subpackage1
import subpackage2
```

This makes sure anytime `package` is imported, it also imports `subpackageX`, as `package.subpackageX`.

In your `subpackageX/__init__.py` you don't include anything.  So in order to get the `package.subpackageX.moduleX` defined, one would have to import it explicitly (e.g. `from package.subpackage1 import module1`)

Note that if you take the underscores approach, in ipython, one could still tab-complete the names prefixed with underscores, if doing `package.subpackage1._<TAB>`.

EDIT:

Other alternatives:

1. In `subpackage1/__init__.py`, import the names you want to expose,
   e.g. `from .module1 import x,y`.  That would make them defined as
   `package.subpackage1.x`, not `package.subpackage1.module1.x`
2. Define the names using the `__all__` directive.  That would not affect tab-completion, but would be a declarative way of saying what the importer should be of interest.  This way, they can also do `from package.subpackage1 import *`.

Comment: thanks.  but if someone does import module1 explicitly, is there another way for me to encourage them to not use the functionality of module3 through module1?  In other words, I'd like my usage of module3 in module1 to be hidden from the user as well as my usage of numpy as np.  is using things like import numpy as _np and from ..subpackage2 import module3 as _module3 the best way to do this?

Comment: You could use underscores, but like you said, that would only discourage it, it would not prevent it, with the disadvantage of making your code less aesthetic.  Why not just leave it as `np`? In python, we believe that "we're all adults here". if they want to access it in a way you didn't intend them to.... well... let them.

Comment: To be honest I don't mind people accessing it how they want to.  I just don't want them to have to wade through all the utility modules I've imported when they are looking for the real functionality of module1 for example which would contain something like class1 and function1

Comment: part 1 of your edit is exactly what I wanted to do ... expose only the useful parts of the modules and not every utility I'd imported to do the work of the modules.  thanks again